# What's the term of art for hardcover books with an illustration printed directly on the cover?

Tags: print-production, terminology, book

Is there a design / printing / bookmaking term of art for case-bound hardcovers with the art not on a dustjacket but on the cover itself (not common in US/UK trade publishing, but found e.g. on many hardcover textbooks and gamebooks, some small press fiction)?

Examples:

[image: Margo Lanagan, _We Three Kids_, PS Publishing]
[image: Seeds & Backman, _Foundations of Astronomy_]
[image: Sourcebooks for _Advanced Dungeons & Dragons,_ First Edition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am from Denmark and we call it *overtræksomslag*, which translates to *wrapped cover*.

When I google *"different kinds of book covers"* I find [this](https://www.createmybooks.com/NL/en/write-a-book/choosing-a-cover-type) site, which calls it **Hardcover Case Wrap**, which seems like the correct term.

Maybe some native english speakers can confirm this?

(By the way, technically the cover isn't printed directly on the cover, but on a thin piece of paper which is then wrapped around a cardboard cover.)

Comment: “Casewrap hardcover” seems pretty common. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although originally the books did not have a dust jacket but had the art printed on the cover, the term cover is the one that corresponds to it. The dust jacket came later. In any case, if it is necessary to specify it, it would be a book without a dust jacket.